# Bypass incapsula in c#

Tags: c#, web-scraping

I am trying to scrape responsibly some data on just-eat.co.uk

Using a webclient I get a page with some javascript code to check that I am not a bot from incapsula.

```
var b="...DATAENCODED...";
for (var i=0;i<b.length;i+=2){z=z+parseInt(b.substring(i, i+2), 16)+",";}z = z.substring(0,z.length-1); eval(eval('String.fromCharCode('+z+')');
```

decoding what is going in eval(eval(...)) gives me

```
try{
    var xhr;
    var t=new Date().getTime();
    var status="start";
    var timing=new Array(3);
    window.onunload=function(){
        timing[2]="r:"+(new Date().getTime()-t);
        document.createElement("img").src="/_Incapsula_Resource?XXXXXXX=52&t=63&d="+encodeURIComponent(status+" ("+timing.join()+")")
    };
    if(window.XMLHttpRequest) {
        xhr=new XMLHttpRequest
    }else{
        xhr=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP")
    }
    xhr.onreadystatechange=function(){
       switch(xhr.readyState){
           case 0:
              status=new Date().getTime()-t+": request not initialized ";
           break;
           case 1:
              status=new Date().getTime()-t+": server connection established";
           break;
           case 2:
              status=new Date().getTime()-t+": request received";
           break;
           case 3:
              status=new Date().getTime()-t+": processing request";
           break;
           case 4:
              status="complete";
              timing[1]="c:"+(new Date().getTime()-t);
              if(xhr.status==200){
                  parent.location.reload()
              }
              break
        }
    };
    timing[0]="s:"+(new Date().getTime()-t);
    xhr.open("GET","/_Incapsula_Resource?SWHANEDL=111...DATA...111,222...DATA...222,333...DATA...333,444...DATA...444",false);
    xhr.send(null)
}
catch(c)
{
    status+=new Date().getTime()-t+" incap_exc: "+c;
    document.createElement("img").src="/_Incapsula_Resource?XXXXXXX=52&t=63&d="+encodeURIComponent(status+" ("+timing.join()+")")
};
```

Is there a way do bypass this with a webclient ? Might be pointless to try since it's running javascript. Can be helpful to have a tool to send requests in a browser like chrome and capture the the results by saving the browser rendered information.

Comment: I further de-obfuscated the code with better line breaks and indentation. Looking at the code, you may be able to just send a request to the correct image URL, but figuring out that URL could be tricky.